# Linearization of Continuity and Euler's equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, waves

I've been stuck on this problem for days, but I just don't get it.

I have, as per title, the [Continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) and [Euler's equation for a fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)) in this form:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla(\rho v) = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial t} + v \cdot \nabla(\rho v) = -\nabla P$$

Where, $\rho$, is the density of the fluid (which is assumed compressible), $v$ is the velocity field of the fluid and $P$ is the pressure.

I need to prove that if the density and the velocity field are perturbed like so:

$$\rho = \rho_0 + \rho_1 \ ;$$

$$v = v_0 + v_1$$

Where, it is assumed that the perturbations are small. Finally if the problem is restricted to a one-dimensional case, the first order response of the system is:

$$\frac{\partial \rho_1}{\partial t} + \rho_0 \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} = 0$$

$$\rho_0 \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho} \frac{\partial \rho_1}{\partial x} = 0$$

My only problem, is with the derivatives of the derivatives that contain $\rho v$ terms, because I get terms like: $$v_0\frac{\partial \rho_1}{\partial x} \ ,$$ if someone could explain to me how to get rid of that term, I'd be really thankful. Thank you in advance, sorry for the long post.